# Statsmodels fit distribution among 0 and 1

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a beta distribution that should be defined between 0 and 1 on a data set that only has samples in a subrange. My problem is that using the `fit()` function will cause the fitted PDF to be defined only between my smallest and largest values. 
For instance, if my dataset has samples between 0.2 and 0.3, what I get is a PDF defined between 0.2 and 0.3, instead of between 0 and 1, as it should be. The code I am using is:

```
ps1 = beta.fit(selected, loc=0, scale=1)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is `beta` from scipy.stats? You should specify which package you are using.

Comment: If it is scipy, then fix loc and scale, i.e. `ps1 = beta.fit(selected, floc=0, fscale=1)`

Answer (score 1):

So:

- you know that the distribution has a=0 and b=1 lower and upper bounds,
- but the sample does not contain any values close to these limits.

This may happen if the distribution truly is a Beta distribution and the alpha and beta parameters are so that the density near 0 and 1 is zero.

In this case, I would suggest to use the maximum likelihood method, restricting the active parameters to alpha and beta, with known a and b parameters.

This is easy with the `MaximumLikelihoodFactory` class of OpenTURNS, which has a `setKnownParameter` method. This method allows to restrict the parameters which are optimized by the maximum likelihood method.

To reproduce this situation, I created a Beta distribution with the following parameters.

```
import openturns as ot
distribution = ot.Beta(3.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0)
sampleSize = 100
sample = distribution.getSample(sampleSize)
```

Fitting a Beta distribution with known a and b parameters is straightforward.

```
factory = ot.MaximumLikelihoodFactory(distribution)
factory.setKnownParameter([0.0, 1.0], [2, 3])
inf_distribution = factory.build(sample)
```

The list `[0.0, 1.0]` contains the values of the a and b parameters and the indices `[2, 3]` are the indices of the parameters in the Beta distribution.
This produces :

```
Beta(alpha = 3.02572, beta = 1.88172, a = 0, b = 1)
```

with sample I simulated.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the suggestion. It's been a few years since I asked the question, but coincidentally I am working on the same issue right now and I'll give your solution a spin.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with a partial solution that does the trick for me: I replicate my samples (for the datasets that are too small) and add dummy samples at 0 and 1. Although that increases the fit error, it is low enough for my purpose.
Also, I asked in Google groups and got [this answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pystatsmodels/p3LMyERf6C4/8eE6J08-AgAJ) that works fine, but its giving me some errors occasionally. I hope this helps anyone with that problem.

Comment: The solution of adding 0 and 1 to the sample is consistent with what you know of the distribution, but inconsistent with the data. Since the data is only in a subrange of the [0, 1] interval, the likelihood that a Beta with 0 and 1 limits should be very low in genral. Hence, this does not sound like a true solution to me.